# Game Lagging due to too much details

Tags: unity

I'm making a car racing game where you drive around hills.

The game has some performance issues. At some point it starts lagging badly. After one day spent on this, I realized that when the car drives through detailed areas with lots of objects, the game starts to lag. It works fine with a simple scenery (eg. just a plane).

Comment: Short of seeing the entire project its going to be hard to say whats causing the problem -- is there any additional script processing when the items mentioned are in the scene ?? More complicated shaders ??

I'd particularly look at the shaders, and the models for the hills and the bridge.. too many vertices can bog things down, as can too many shader passes... though I'm running test apps with vertex counts in excess of 100k per scene and not having a problem.. but the shaders are pretty simple... single pass, no lighting, no ambient occlusion, no shadows, etc

Lastly> what GPU are you using

Comment: I'm using  Intel(R) HD Graphics Family with Approx 1696MB Memory

Comment: Sir, One More request please. as I'm new to Unity,  so I Couldn't find a way to  get rid of these Complicated shaders, even i'm unable to find out what shaders is creating problem.    Please Sir,   Help me On this too.   Please

Comment: Please have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Your hardware sucks btw. Make a release build and try that, it should increase your framerate at the expense of everything the editor offers you while playing.

Answer (score 1):

If you know the problem is a too detailed environment then you should be able to fix it by toning down the details.

You don't need to model every leaf of every tree, instead use a few intersecting textured transparent planes to create the illusion of volume.

You don't need to model the window sills of the buildings you are whizzing past, just use a simple box and and bump-mapping to create the illusion of depth.

You can set the shadows statically with textures so you can disable receiving shadows on those objects. Only the road surface and your car will need to be able to have a shadow cast on it.

Comment: I Understand what you say, but the Thing is I'm using Unity Free Version and Scene is one hill behind another hill and so on to 4 Hills. So I should i use Bump-maping and texture transparent for this.